# How do I project an element of an array in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, projection

I have a mongo document that contains something like

```
{date: [2018, 3, 22]}
```

and when I try to project this into a flat JSON structure with these fields concatenated, I always get an array with 0 elements, eg. just extracting the year with

```
db.getCollection('blah').aggregate([
  {$project: {year: "$date.0"}}
])
```

I get

```
{"year" : []}
```

even though matching on a similar expression works fine, eg.

```
db.getCollection('blah').aggregate([
  {$match: {"$date.0": 2018}}
])
```

selects the documents I would expect just fine.

What am I doing wrong?  I've searched mongo documentation and stackoverflow but could find nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `$project` you should use `$arrayElemAt` instead of dot notation which works only for queries.

```
db.getCollection('blah').aggregate([
 {$project: {year: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$date", 0 ] }}}
])
```

More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

Comment: Great!  That works.  I find it very confusing to know which notation works in which context in mongodb.